# Create a bool Linq to SQL Expression from an Int Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

In Linq to SQL I have an expression that returns an int, and I want to make an expression based  on that expression that returns a boolean. The int can be used for `OrderBy(score)` and the boolean can be used for `Where(ifScore)`. I'm unable to figure out how to use score to define `ifScore`, and would appreciate some help.

```
Expression<Func<Model, int>> score = p =>
            (testList.Count() > 0 && p.Name.Contains(testList.FirstOrDefault()) ? 1 : 0);

Expression<Func<Model, bool>> ifScore = p =>
            //how to say if score > 2
```

Comment: Your first expression can only return an int of 1 or 0, which is basically a true / false. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how well this will play with LINQ to SQL, but you can use [**`Expression.GreaterThan`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356438.aspx) to create the appropriate binary-expression, and then it's just a matter of creating the right `Expression<TDelegate>` from that.

```
var body = Expression.GreaterThan(score.Body, Expression.Constant(2));
var ifScore = Expression.Lambda<Func<Model, bool>>(body, score.Parameters);
```

The final expression will look something like:

```
p => (( testList.Count() > 0
        && p.Name.Contains(testList.FirstOrDefault()) ? 1 : 0 ) > 2
```

Of course, that does look a little nonsensical because it can *never* be true. Are you sure you intended to do this? Perhaps you really want to compare it with `1` or `0` for equality  instead?

Comment: Thanks. It is just a sample, but your 2 lines up top works perfectly.